# Dates search in Drupal (greater than, less than) using CCK / views / facelet?

Tags: search, drupal, date

I'm working in a site that manage events (like parties). Each event could have several fields, including date, that the user could add thanks to CCK module.
Now, the problem is when I have to search using those fields.
I could not find how to search for events between a range of dates.
I discover the facelet module, which is pretty good, and it is very useful for some kind of search, but as far as I can see it is not possible search in a range.
Also I do some testing using views, but again, with no results. I can not find how to search a date "greater than" and "less than".
I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this a few days ago:

[Drupal Views how to filter items overlapping a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994606/drupal-views-how-to-filter-items-overlapping-a-date-range/2994615#2994615)

The Date module will provide new Filters in your View that are date based. You then tell Views to use a start and end date that is +/- your target date. You could also expose this field, and it will show two fields for picking dates and use those as filters.

Comment: Kevin, sorry for the noise, I really search, even here, but I can not find what the answer. You put me in the right way, and I discover that my mistake was that was using Date as a CCK field, instead of using independently. 
Thank you so much!